# SQL syntax error: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException"

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, syntax-error

```java
run:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':\\wallpaper\\a.jpg)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
    at stage.Dossier.jPanel7MouseClicked(Dossier.java:355)
    at stage.Dossier.access$500(Dossier.java:30)
    at stage.Dossier$6.mouseClicked(Dossier.java:171)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This My code

```java
JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser("D:\\");
            f.showOpenDialog(null);
            FileNameExtensionFilter fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter("IMAGES", "png", "jpg", "jpeg");
            f.setFileFilter(fnef);
            File selected = f.getSelectedFile();
            String selectedPath = selected.getAbsolutePath();

            Image getAbsolutePath = null;
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(selectedPath);
            Image image = icon.getImage();
            selectedPath = selectedPath.replace("\\","\\\\");

            // INSERT IN MYSQL
            String sql = "INSERT INTO stage1 (ATTESTATION) VALUES (" + selectedPath + ")";
            pst = (PreparedStatement) cnx.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "succes!!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating SQL text:

```sql
INSERT INTO stage1 (ATTESTATION) VALUES (C:\\wallpaper\\a.jpg)
```

That is definitely not valid SQL syntax, as the error message says.

The value needs to be single-quoted:

```sql
INSERT INTO stage1 (ATTESTATION) VALUES ('C:\\wallpaper\\a.jpg')
```

Except you don't want to do that. You actually have a `PreparedStatement`, so **use it**:

```java
String selectedPath = selected.getAbsolutePath();
String sql = "INSERT INTO stage1 (ATTESTATION) VALUES (?)";
try (PreparedStatement pst = cnx.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pst.setString(1, selectedPath);
    pst.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out specifically that when you use the `?` as a parameter placeholder, you must _not_ put that inside the single-quotes as if it were a string literal. You did it correctly in your answer above, but some readers don't understand the difference.